# transport Project from windows to Raspberry pi

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi

How do I Move it up and running my own project that I worked on Visual Studio from Windows to Rasberry pi

Comment: You haven't provided much information here.  What kind of project/application is it?  Is the Pi host running SSH, SFTP, SMB, NFS, FTP, etc.?  Which of those do you want to use and what problem are you having with them?  Or are you hoping to publish the project directly from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean transfer projects from Windows to Raspberry PI?, anyway, Raspberry PI like any other remote desktop, you can use `WinSCP` from your Windows machine to see your files and folders inside your remote machine, and you can copy-paste files and folders from and to your Windows machine or also from and to remote Raspberry PI, also, you can from this tool modify your files and folders, by edit, add, or remove.
You just need to connect to your Raspberry PI using the same IP address and password that you are using to access your device from `Remote Desktop Connection` or `Putty`.
And finally, if you want to use Visual Studio to code inside Raspberry PI, you can use the same tools, just search for your file and open it using Visual Studio or Visual Code.

Comment: Thank you for the response, my Rasperi system and my computer made a program on a Visual studio , not a Visual studio code. I'm tired of trying, I also tried to transfer the program file, but I couldn't show me the error